# Custom function for tabs creating duplicate tabs

Tags: php, wordpress

```
//checks that we are on current page and highlights tab as active if so
    if(is_page($page_name)){
        echo " <li><a href='$href' class='current_page_item'> $tabname</a></li>";
    }
    else {  
    }

    if(is_single() && $singlelight=="this_one") {
        echo " <li><a href='$href' class='current_page_item'> $tabname</a></li>";
    }
    else {
        echo " <li><a href='$href' > $tabname</a></li>";
    }
```

The code above works as I expected - highlight tabs using the WordPress function `is_single` and `is_page`. The problem is it generates 2 tabs for the active one in the menu. So my menu looks like this when <kbd>Home</kbd> is active.

`Home Home Faq Blog Contact`

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the first if statement?

What if you tried:

```
    if(is_single() && $singlelight=="this_one" && is_page($page_name)) {
        echo " <li><a href='$href' class='current_page_item'> $tabname</a></li>";
    }
    else {
        echo " <li><a href='$href' > $tabname</a></li>";
    }
```

Comment: that eliminates my duplicate tabs but the 1st if statement checks against is_page to highlight the tab. so no highlighting with this code which is the point of the function.